# Force TLS1.2 for visual studio debugging

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I have a website that fails when I disable TLS 1.0/1.1.
I want to debug it using Visual Studio and integrated IIS Express.

How to disable TLS1.0/1.1 in this case to force TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows TLS versions (and cryptographic suites) are defined globally in the registry. This is covered by various articles online; eg. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/07/25/disabling-tls-1-0-on-your-windows-2008-r2-server-just-because-you-still-have-one/

But an easier option may be to just use a browser in which you've disabled older TLS versions: IIS Express is responding to the requests from the browser and the TLS version (and cryptographic suite) is agreed mutually by client and server as part of the TLS handshake.

Details depend on the browser. In Firefox it is the `security.tls.version.min` and `security.tls.version.max` settings in `about:config`.