# Enabling TLS1.2 or TLS1.3 in c# asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, tls1.2, asp.net-core-3.1

I am building a web app using asp.net core 3.1.

I want to enable TLS1.2 (or TLS1.3 if it works and is backward compatible.)

I have a web site running under IIS Express that is failing the SSL certificate.

[image: Bad SSL certificate]

The console shows the following error:
[image: Bad SSL certificate console message]

I followed some instructions and I thought I could solve the problem by executing the following code in CreateHostBuilder in Program.cs:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(s => {
                        s.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(k =>
                        {
                            k.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
                        });
                    }).UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

I have run the application and it is still failing with the same error.

I am also running an implementation of IdentityServer4 on my local machine. That does not seem to have the same problem.
[image: Good site]

The identityserver4 site is secure.

How do I force my site to use TLS1.2 (or later)?

Comment: Try to run the website just using Kestrel, and check whether the warning disappear or not? Perhaps the issue is related to the IIS configuration, it not enable TLS1.2, check [How to use TLS 1.2 in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://karthiktechblog.com/aspnetcore/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-asp-net-core-2-0-and-above). And from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#security), it seems that Windows and macOS do not yet support TLS 1.3. .NET Core 3.0 will support TLS 1.3 on these operating systems when support becomes available.

Comment: Reference resource:[Kestrel Endpoint configuration for TLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration) and  [Force TLS1.2 for visual studio debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300855/force-tls1-2-for-visual-studio-debugging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the supported TLS protocols here:

```
webBuilder.UseKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.AddServerHeader = false;

    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);

    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443,
        options =>
        {
            var cert = ...Load TLS certificate;

            options.UseHttps(serverCertificate: cert, configureOptions: httpsOptions =>
            {
                httpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
            });
        });
});
```

See also

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22563
- https://karthiktechblog.com/aspnetcore/how-to-use-tls-1-2-in-asp-net-core-2-0-and-above

Comment: That looks like an older version of dot net core, but thanks for the idea, I'll give it a try.

Comment: It's ASP.NET Core 3.1, its how I set that in production. I also added a few links to the answer. Hope that makes it an acceptable answer.

Comment: Ahh ok, I thought it was no longer using UseKestrel (which is the default anyway) and all that configuration was done in ConfigureWebHostDefaults. I'm not near my computer at the moment but I'll check it out.

Comment: I usually don't use IIS Express as most of my deployments goes to Linux containers and I use Kestrel directly on the public internet.

Comment: It turns out I might not need to do any of that. As soon as I switched over to use a self hosted server, it recognised TLS1.2. So it must be something to do with TLS1.2 not being active in IISExpress.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, Does this make this an acceptable answer?